# How can I combine multiple bodies into one in Farseer?

Tags: c#, farseer-physics-engine

I want to create a windmill in Farseer, but I don't know how to combine the 3 windmill sails bodies to one body. During gameplay, the sails could get destroyed. For example, if another body hits one of the sails, then this sail will be destroyed, separating the sails. This means the parts should be able to come apart again.

I'll use the following sprites to create the windmill:

[image: Windmill pole]
[image: Windmill sail]
[image: Windmill ball]

The final windmill should look like this:

[image]

What method should I use to combine these together, but have them able to separate when destroyed?

Comment: What is the problem you're having when you try to make them one body?

Comment: If I use one sprite for the three windsails, then it is impossible to delete one of the sails. Because if something hits a sail, then the sail should get deleted. Is it possible to combine Windmillsail1, Windmillsail2 and Windmillsail3 to one body or attach the three bodies together? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can't you just attach wings via joints, and then destroy joints dynamically?